# What is the percentage of woman without a hymen?

Tags: health-education, physiology, reference-request

The Wikipedia entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymen) suggests that Hymen can be completed absent inborn. I read through the textbook referred by Wikipedia, but that textbook does not include any data on this; the textbook also made this claim without any reference to experimental observations or medical cases. How could an academic textbook claim something without valid data or evidence?

My question is, what is the approximate percentage of women born without hymen?

Comment: The wikipedia article cites 36 references. Are you sure none of those citations answer your question?

Comment: @CareyGregory Only the first reference was cited for that specific statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1115047/ a hymen appears to be absent in < 0.03% patients (citation of a much older paper: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3627892/).

Comment: Very interesting literature! So hymen is generally present even in adolescents! Do you have related knowledge on adults? Something like studying the natural decay of hymen when aging.